# How to use passed select list in an editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to create an editor template that will create a "bootstrap style" radio buttons for each value from a passed select list (just like the `Html.DropDownFor` method create a dropdown list)

So i have the call in my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FaultTypeID,"RadioButtonList", 
        new SelectList(Model.AllowdeFaultTypes, "FaultTypeID", "FaultTypeName"))
```

and now the template of RadioButtonList:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Items"] as SelectList)
{
    <a>@item.Text</a> <b>@item.Value</b>
}
```

but the conversion fails and i get a `NullReferanceExeption`.
By reflection i see that the `ViewData["Items"]` value is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<CamelotFaultManagement.DAL.FaultType>`

The problem is i really don't want to tightly couple the `RadioButtonList` editor template with `CamelotFaultManagement.DAL.FaultType` class, its just don't make any sense to do that. I want a generic editor template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your editor template you seem to be using some `ViewData["Items"]` property which you never set. If you want to use such property make sure you have assigned it:

```
@Html.EditorFor(
    model => model.FaultTypeID,
    "RadioButtonList", 
    new { Items = new SelectList(Model.AllowdeFaultTypes, "FaultTypeID", "FaultTypeName") }
)
```

This being said, your approach with using some ViewData stuff seems totally wrong to me.

I would simply define a view model (as always in ASP.NET MVC):

```
public class RadioListViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
}
```

and then you could have your editor template strongly typed to this view model. Of course your editor template will be now stored in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RadioListViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model IRadioListViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a>@item.Text</a> <b>@item.Value</b>
}
```

and now all that's left is to use this view model in your main view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public RadioListViewModel FaultTypes { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then inside your view simply render the corresponding editor template:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FaultTypes)
```

Simple, conventional, strongly typed.

Comment: My god ! i thought i passed it .. had to create an anonymous object and forgot !! Thank You!

Comment: Please read my recommended approach as well before getting into the mess of ViewData.

Comment: I have a problem with your recommendation as I'm trying to create an editor for a `TypeID` which is integer type and i want to have a closed set of types from which the user can select so I don't see how i can use an editor for a `RadioListViewModel` to enter a value for the `TypeID` property..

Comment: If you want to create an editor template for a `TypeID` property which is an integer you shouldn't need to any collections inside. If you need them then you are doing it wrong and your editor template is not using the correct type because you need additional information. So that's where the view model comes in. You could use an object type instead of integer if you want to make it a little more generic. But you should think about uniforming your identity types used across the application. Having strings, guids, short, long integers, timestamps, ... is probably to be avoided.

Comment: So you are saying that is there is a limited DB driven list of values for 'TypeID' it should be of a list-type which will hold all values and the selected one ?

Comment: Who said anything about DB. We are talking about view models here. Normally your domain models should be bound to the database. So feel free to perform whatever transformations you like when mapping between your domain models and your view models. But even in your database you might want to use consistent approach for your ids across the various tables.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, sorry as it's an old post, but there's no way of getting rid of the ofreach in the editor template is there? I was struggling with something similar yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296717/avoid-foreach-using-editor-template-in-mv-radiobutton-within-an-mvc-view